# What account to use in sessionstate connectionstring

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am working on a Website that was donated to our institution, right now I'm trying to decide exactly how to set up two connection strings (CS) in the Web.config file (some of the details in these connection strings were redacted by the donator). 
The CS I have a question about is referenced in sessionState:

```
<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="DevelopmentSessionState" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

I'm trying to determine what type of Account I should be using for the UserID in the SessionState CS. In order to get the Website functional I used the sa account, but I know this isn't a good idea - I'm looking for an account to replace sa. I have no idea if this is a user I should define in SQL Server, or if I should use a pre-existing account, or what type of access this user should have.

I am also fuzzy on the idea of why a separate connection string is needed for Session State. The Website's c# code uses the other CS explicitly to connect to the db, but the only reference to the SessionState CS is in Web.config. I have read a lot about Session State and SQLServer mode that past few days, but I haven't found any recommendations for what account to use or why a separate CS is needed for SessionState.

Thanks,
Chris

Update: This is the stack trace from the abend that happens when I substitute my UserID for sa in the Session State CS (I replaced my actual User ID with USERID):

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Failed to login to session state SQL server for user 'USERID'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Failed to login to session state SQL server for user 'USERID'.

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'USERID'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4876535
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1121
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +144
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +367
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +225
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +431
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
System.Web.SessionState.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo) +93

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to login to session state SQL server for user 'USERID'.]




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491
```

Comment: Generally you can share the sessionState database between multiple applications, so having one account is an accepted practice. Whether you choose to use SQL or Integrated Windows Auth is a design choice you should weigh against your organization's overall strategy. For example, some environments prefer to use Windows Auth to avoid putting system passwords in the hands of developers.

Comment: Thanks mjw - this helps a lot. I should be able to choose an appropriate account now.

Answer (score 1):

I did finally succeed in creating a user that worked in the Session State CS.

To begin with, rather than running InstallSqlState.sql I ran aspnet_regsql.exe. The SQL file had a warning not to run it standalone and that I should instead use aspnet_regsql.exe, so I did that. I used the following options:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -ssadd -sstype p -E -S servername
```

This created db ASPState and meant that I had to use mode="SQLServer" in  in web.config.

I also had to add role 'public' to ASPState as suggested here: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/969708.aspx 
This post included giving 'public' permissions but did not talk about which ones would be needed, so I had to experiment with that until the CS worked. Permissions were added by right clicking on db ASPState, choosing Properties, selecting Permissions, highlighting database role 'public', then checking off permissions under the 'Grant' heading.

Finally I logged in to SQL Server Management Studio using SQL Server Authentication and created a new user S1. I only gave 'Connect' permission to S1 using the same navigation described above. S1 replaced sa in the session state connection string. Here is the web.config entry for the session state CS. Obviously I changed the pw and servername, but you can see the format I used:

```
<add name="DVSessionState" connectionString="Data Source=servername;User Id='S1';Password='password'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following steps describe how to run the InstallSqlState.sql and the UninstallSqlState.sql script files to configure SQL Server mode session state management.**

In SQL Query Analyzer, on the File menu, click Open.
In the Open Query File dialog box, browse to the `InstallSqlState.sql` script file, and then click Open. By default, `InstallSqlState.sql` is located in one of the following folders:

```
system drive\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\
system drive\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\
```

After `InstallSqlState.sql` opens in SQL Query Analyzer, click Execute on the Query menu to run the script.

Before you run the `UninstallSqlState.sql` script file to uninstall SQL Server mode session state management configuration, you must stop the w3svc process. To do this, follow these steps:

1. On the Windows Start menu, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK to open a command prompt.
2. At the command prompt, type `net stop w3svc`. You receive confirmation that the w3svc process is stopped.
3. In SQL Query Analyzer, on the File menu, click Open.
4. In the Open Query File dialog box, browse to the `UninstallSqlState.sql` script file, and then click Open. By default, `UninstallSqlState.sql` is located in one of the following folders:

   system drive\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\
   system drive\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\
5. After `UninstallSqlState.sql` opens in SQL Query Analyzer, click Execute on the Query menu to run the script.
6. After you uninstall SQL Server mode session state management configuration, you must restart the w3svc service. To restart the w3svc process, type `net start w3svc` at a command prompt.

**Modify the Web.config File of Your Application**

To implement ASP.NET SQL Server mode session state management, you must modify the `<sessionState>` element of your application's Web.config file as follows:

1. Set the mode attribute of the `<sessionState>` element to `SQLServer` to indicate that session state is stored in SQL Server.
2. Set the `sqlConnectionString` attribute to specify the connection string for SQL Server. For example:

   sqlConnectionString="data source=MySQLServer;user id=;password="

Note: The user, `<user name>`, must have permissions to perform this operation on the database.

The modified `<sessionState>` element should appear as follows:

```
<sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />
```

Note: Ensure that you use the correct case when you specify the `<sessionState>` element and the associated attribute values. This code is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for their helpful information - I thought I had this figured out but I have been unable to find any user but sa that works in this connection string. I think my problem is not knowing what permissions the user must have. Mohammed, I know you said the user must have rights to perform this operation, but I don't know what 'this operation' means... Connect to the database ? Are these rights defined in SQL Server Management Studio?